# Interface Builder, @IBOutlet and protocols for delegate and dataSource in Swift

Tags: swift, interface-builder, iboutlet

Can't connect delegate property of `CustomView` declared as @IBOutlet to`ViewController` in Interface Builder – simply can't establish a connection.

Here's the code

```
class CustomView: UIView {
     @IBOutlet var delegate: CustomViewDelegate?
}

@objc protocol CustomViewDelegate {
     ...
}


class ViewController: UIViewController, CustomViewDelegate {
     ...
}
```

`@objc` is used because of [swift protocol, IBOutlet property cannot have non-object type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24561490/swift-protocol-iboutlet-property-cannot-have-non-object-type), don't know why `protocol CustomViewDelegate: class {}` doesn't work.

Anyone else came across something like that?

Comment: Does your `UIViewController` in Interface Builder have its class specifically set to `ViewController`? Also, it's normally a requirement (last I checked) that `@IBOutlet` properties be defined as implicitly unwrapped types, like so: `CustomViewDelegate!`. This allows them to be `nil` at instantiation, while allowing you to use them without optional binding after they've been wired up.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

From the Xcode release notes:

> Interface Builder does not support connecting to an outlet in a Swift file when the outlet’s type is a protocol.
>
> Workaround: Declare the outlet's type as AnyObject or NSObject, connect objects to the outlet using Interface Builder, then change the outlet's type back to the protocol.

**EDIT:** Xcode 9 beta 3 release notes say that this workaround should no longer be necessary.

Comment: Wowzer! This worked, thanks. Apple... please get it together!

Comment: Nope. "Class is not key-value compliant" after the change back to Protocol type.

Comment: This only partially worked for me.  In one case, where I defined my own delegate on a UIView to be hooked up to a UIViewController, it worked.  In another, where I define my delegate on a UIViewController to be hooked up to another UIViewController, it does not.  I have tried so many configurations.  Any ideas @matt what may be going on here?

Comment: "In another, where I define my delegate on a UIViewController to be hooked up to another UIViewController, it does not" That makes no sense to me, @josephap. You can _never_ draw an outlet connection of _any_ kind from one view controller to another view controller in a storyboard, so I can't imagine what you were trying to do in the first place. This has nothing do with Swift at all. It's just a fact about how nibs work. - See my book: http://apeth.com/iOSBook/ch07.html#SECconnectionBetweenNibs

Comment: Yes, Matt, I realize now. I haven't used Storyboards all that much, and just found out that you can only connect outlets within view controllers, not between them.  I did, separately, have a Swift related issue which your answer helped with.  Thanks.

Comment: Now I'm torn as to whether I should switch back to Objective-C and/or ditch storyboards in favour of pure code.  The main reason I'm using storyboards at the moment is because I'm writing a Cocoa app and I only have experience with iOS.  Also it's nice to develop subviews with `@IBDesignable`.

Comment: It's February 2016 and still not fixed. Luckily there is this workaround.

Comment: Should be fixed in Xcode 9 beta 3, according to the release notes.

Answer (score 16):

[Adam Waite provides a nice workaround.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32796103/543875) I however prefer the following solution as it emphasizes the workaround and the extra property can also easily be removed once Xcode gets fixed.

```
class CustomView: UIView {
    @IBOutlet
    public var delegate: CustomViewDelegate?

    /// Workaround for Xcode bug that prevents you from connecting the delegate in the storyboard.
    /// Remove this extra property once Xcode gets fixed.
    @IBOutlet
    public var ibDelegate: AnyObject? {
        get { return delegate }
        set { delegate = newValue as? CustomViewDelegate }
    }

    func someMethod() {
        // Here we always refer to `delegate`, not `ibDelegate`
        delegate?.onSomethingHappened()
    }
}

@objc protocol CustomViewDelegate {
    ...
}
```

Hey, is this bug already one and a half years old?

Answer (score 10):

An elegant workaround：

```
#if TARGET_INTERFACE_BUILDER
@IBOutlet open weak var delegate: AnyObject?
#else
open weak var delegate: CustomViewDelegate?
#endif
```

See：
https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSPagerView/blob/master/Sources/FSPagerView.swift#L88

Answer (score 9):

Another that's not pretty but:

```
@IBOutlet weak var ibDelegate: NSObject?
@IBOutlet weak var ibDataSource: NSObject?
var delegate: MultipleButtonViewDelegate? { return ibDelegate as? MultipleButtonViewDelegate }
var dataSource: MultipleButtonViewDataSource? { return ibDataSource as? MultipleButtonViewDataSource }
```

Comment: Good answer! Use this way to prevent change type usually the Outlet.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old thread, but I thought I'd point out that as of Xcode 9 beta 3, it is now possible to connect a custom delegate written in swift to interface builder.

According to the release notes

> Interface Builder now recognizes outlets, actions, and inspectable
>   properties declared on classes which have a Swift protocol extension.
>   (22201035)

```
// Can connect this to interface builder now    
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var myDelegate: TheNewDelegate?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, the reason was the table view was `nil` at the point I attempted to set it's datasource and delegate. This was due to the designated initializer calling `initWithNibName:bundle:` which does not guarantee [initialized connections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2126393/1803879). Deferring my delegate and datasource setting to `viewDidload` worked like a charm.