# Can not connect custom protocol delegate from storyboard in Xcode 6.1

Tags: swift, ios8, interface-builder, xcode6, xcode6.1

I just upgraded my mac to 10.10 and Xcode to 6.1,

found a strange thing which about storyboard,

my case is using a swift project, can not connect custom protocol delegate from storyboard anymore.

the old connected which comes with old version of Xcode is fine, but I can not connect any new delegate anymore.

even I can not reconnect the old one once I removed the connected.

Does anyone occur this situation ??

**============================== Updated ==============================**

> View Class

```
@objc public protocol VideoViewResizeDelegate {

    func shouldVideoViewResetLayout(videoView: GvVideoView) -> Bool;

}

@IBOutlet var resizeDelegate: VideoViewResizeDelegate?;
```

> ViewController Class

```
@IBDesignable public class ViewController: UIViewController, VideoViewResizeDelegate {

...

}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code/storyboard? It sounds like the subclass is not set on the view controller you are trying to connect.

Comment: I can connect the delegate by storyboard in Xcode 6.0, it was the same code, can not connect anymore once I remove the connected

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interface Builder, @IBOutlet and protocols for delegate and dataSource in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180268/interface-builder-iboutlet-and-protocols-for-delegate-and-datasource-in-swift)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051

> Interface Builder
>
> Interface Builder does not support connecting to an outlet in a Swift
>   file when the outlet’s type is a protocol. Declare the outlet's type
>   as AnyObject or NSObject, connect objects to the outlet using
>   Interface Builder, then change the outlet's type back to the protocol.
>   (17023935)

it's sucks...

Comment: And in 2017 ... it is still the case.
I don't get where they're going with all this @ Apple. Swift compiler taking huge amounts of time to compile some simple statements, incremental compilation bugs causing rebuilds of all your files for small changes, compiler crashes, inconsistent compiler error messages, interface builder problems, and ZERO refactoring support  in Xcode. Yeah, this is really the language of the future for everything Apple related ...

Answer (score 8):

It's 2017....

Using swift 3, this will work:

```
open class YourClass: UIView {

    #if TARGET_INTERFACE_BUILDER
    @IBOutlet open weak var delegate: AnyObject?
    #else
    open weak var delegate: YourClassDelegate?
    #endif

}
```

A **precondition** is:

YourClassDelegate must be decorated with **@objc**

For example:

```
@objc public protocol MyDelegate: class {
    func myFunc()
    func myFunc2()
}
```

#### Update

This should be fixed in Xcode 9

Comment: Hey Tom, I tested it in Xcode 8.3, and Swift 3.1, it works for me. By the way, there is a precondition: your delegate protocol must be decorated by @objc

Comment: Wow.. Thanks man.. it works for me.. I was looking for this... There must be a way and here you gave it to me. Thanks